# Getting error when tried to use target pointcut designator in Spring AOP

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I'm trying a simple example of **target** pointcut designator in Spring AOP

But I'm not sure, what I'm missing here. Facing the below error.

> BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'fooDao' is expected to be
>   of type 'com.opensource.kms.FooDao' but was actually of type
>   'com.opensource.kms.$Proxy19'

**FooDao Class**

```
package com.opensource.kms;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

interface BarDao {
    String m();
}

@Component
public class FooDao implements BarDao {   
    public String m() {
        System.out.println("implementation of m");
        return "This is return value";
    }
}
```

**Aspect Class**

```
package com.opensource.kms;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class SecurityService {

    @Pointcut("target(com.opensource.kms.FooDao)")
    public void myPointCut() {}

    @Before("myPointCut()")
    public void beforeMethod() {
        System.out.println("beforeMethod");
    }
}
```

**Config Class**

```
package com.opensource.kms;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan("com.opensource.kms")
public class JavaConfig {

}
```

**MainApp Class**

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JavaConfig.class);
FooDao ob = ctx.getBean("fooDao", FooDao.class);
System.out.println("data -> "+ob.m());
ctx.close();
```

Could someone help me out here, not sure what steps I need to update in the above code in order to use target designator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring by default uses JDK dynamic proxies for target classes.

Internally in Java proxies are created using interfaces:

```
public class DebugProxy implements java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler {

    private Object obj;

    public static Object newInstance(Object obj) {
        return java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            obj.getClass().getClassLoader(),
            obj.getClass().getInterfaces(),
            new DebugProxy(obj));
    }

    private DebugProxy(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}
```

Here obj is your target class == FooDao. It has only one interface BarDao.

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html

For your class FooDao will be created proxy instance based on the interface BarDao, because it is the only interface it has.

When you call

```
FooDao ob = ctx.getBean("fooDao", FooDao.class);
```

There will be no bean of class FooDao in the spring container because of aop proxy. The name of the bean will be the same because by default name is taken from class. But the object will be NOT FooDao any more. It will be spring proxy object created from your interface BarDao.

That is why if you change FooDao.class -> BarDao.class everything will be ok:

```
BarDao ob = ctx.getBean("fooDao", BarDao.class);
```

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies

[image]

Comment: Super!! @Dmitrii